# Programe received "Exec BAD_ACCESS" In CIDetector

Tags: objective-c

HI I am trying to use the facedector with IOS. When I execute it , it gives the above error at

```
 CIDetector *detector=[CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:nil options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracyLow forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy]];
```

What does that mean? How do I overcome this?

Comment: It means your program tried to access memory it wasn't allowed to access.  What does the backtrace say?

Comment: There are a lot of errors that can lead to BAD_ACCESS. Often, it is with regard to memory management issues. You'll have to break up what you're doing bit by bit to see where the error is.